# HTML5 label for attribute clarification

Tags: html

A quote from HTML5 final specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for):

> The `for` attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the `ID` of a `labelable element` in the same Document as the label element. If the attribute is specified and there is an element in the Document whose `ID` is equal to the value of the `for` attribute, **and the first such element** is a `labelable element`, then that element is the label element's labeled control.

The last phrase is worded strangely: it talks about "**the first such element**" among a single element and seems to imply that there can be more than a single element in a document with the same ID. Was the part in bold meant to be read as "**and that element**"?

EDIT. People answering my question seems to believe the spec is defining a behavior in case one of the spec rules (unique IDs) is broken. This sounds totally implausible to me. If you break the rules in the spec you do it at your own peril and get the undefined behavior, period. Never have I seen the spec that says: here's the rule but if you break it, don't worry, things still gonna work like so and so.

Comment: I've added this to my answer below, to address your concerns:
In VBScript there is a concept of "Control Arrays" that are created by giving controls the same ID. They are then differentiated and addressed as ID(0), ID(1), etc. This concept, implemented like this, does not exist in JavaScript.

VBScript should no longer be used for client-side scripting but it does still exist. So while IDs should be unique, to duplicate them is not forbidden.

Comment: "Forbidden" is probably not the best term to describe this. It is _invalid_ to have duplicate `id` attributes and the spec is describing the behavior of the browser when it encounters this invalid condition. In general, browsers are tolerant of invalid conditions in markup and seek to repair them or fallback to a reasonable behavior when possible.

Comment: @steveax Browsers are tolerant - yes, but spec taking into account breaking one of its rules? There are SO many things that could break HTML5 rules, following your logic HTML5 should have taken into account them all (or a lot more)? Yet it does not do it, except only here in this particular place (about `label` `for`) - which makes me think this was a typo rather than deliberate taking into account such invalid markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the quoted phrase from HTML5 specification does not have a typo and indeed defines a behavior in case one of the other specification rules (IDs must be unique) is broken. Here is a quote from another W3C specification (W3C DOM4) worded in a way that again takes into account the existence of elements with a duplicate IDs in a document (notice the part in bold):

http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid

> The `getElementById(elementId)` method must return **the first** element, in tree order, within context object's descendants, whose ID is `elementId`, and null if there is no such element otherwise.

The reason why the W3C deemed necessary to define a behavior in case one of the specification rules (IDs must be unique) is broken remains a mystery, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak for the authors, but I think it was meant to be read as is.

> If the attribute is specified and there is an element in the Document whose ID is equal to the value of the for attribute, and the **first such element** is a `labelable` element, then that element is the label element's labeled control.

Notice that I emphasized *first such element*. Consider a scenario where you have two forms. There is a possibility that there are two `input`s with the same `id` in different forms. And you might use two `label`s to represent each of the inputs. What the spec meant was that the `label`s are `for` the first `input` with a matching `id` in the document. In other words, if you have two sets of a `label` with `for=elm` and an `input` with `for=elm`, both of the `label`s will point to the **the first `input`**.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxg5rrk6/2/

Also, I highly recommend you don't use represent two `input`s in the same page with the same `id`, though it might be apparent to you by now that it will break your page.

Answer (score 1):

It addresses the fact that, while there **should** only ever be one element with a unique ID, there could possibly be more, either by design or error.  In this case, the label will only apply to the first one.

**Note:**
*I have completely rewritten this answer.  I originally assumed the concept of "Control Arrays" only applied to the now depreciated VBScript engine.  Upon further investigation I have found that JavaScript still supports them.*

There is a little-documented and **UNSUPPORTED** concept of "Control Arrays" that are created by giving controls the same ID.  They are then differentiated and addressed as ID[0], ID[1], etc.  Note that the JavaScript code does not use:

```
document.getElementById("theDivs")
```

If it did, the request would follow the spec and only return the **first** element.  Instead, the elements are addressed directly as:

```
theDivs[0]...
```

Run the below code snippet to see how the three identically named DIVs can be addressed in JavaScript and also have the CSS applied.

**IMPORTANT:** I am in NO WAY suggesting that this technique should ever be used. The information here is only meant to illustrate one reason why the HTML spec doesn't explicitly forbid multiple uses of the same ID.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  theDivs[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  theDivs[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  theDivs[2].style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
#theDivs {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="theDivs">I'm the 1st div with ID = "theDivs"</div>
  <div id="theDivs">I'm the 2nd div with ID = "theDivs"</div>
  <div id="theDivs">I'm the 3rd div with ID = "theDivs"</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why would the spec first define a rule (forbid non-unique ID) and then phrase the next rule taking into account that the previous rules could be broken?

Comment: In VBScript there is a concept of "Control Arrays" that are created by giving controls the same ID.  They are then differentiated and addressed as ID(0), ID(1), etc.  This concept, implemented like this, does not exist in JavaScript.

So while IDs **should** be unique, to duplicate them is not forbidden.

I think I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Nowhere in HTML5 spec is said that inserting a new element in the document with duplicate ID is allowed. As such doing it renders the document invalid (since HTML5 prohibits non-unique IDs within the same document). Invalid document = undefined behavior, no need to take that in the account in the definition of other spec rules.

Comment: @PowerGamer, I'm not sure if you are trying to disagree with what I said or you just don't understand it.  Please clarify.  Please note that nowhere in the HTML 5 spec are they forbidden either.  If they were, this conversation would not be taking place.  Also, VBScript is depreciated and should not be used for client-side scripting anymore.  So this is not an issue in HTML 5.

Comment: `The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree` here http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute which means the spec forbids non-unique IDs, regardless of how those non-unique IDs might get into the document.

Comment: And again, this does not apply when using VBScript, which has a mechanism to correctly utilize multiple IDs.

Comment: Whatever VBScript allows, HTML5 rules still apply to HTML5 conformant documents meaning non-unique IDs violate the spec and the document is non-conformant. You can't really believe that, when stating one of the rules, HTML5 spec takes into account behavior of some 3rd party language that violates another HTML5 rule.

Comment: I understand how this must look weird to you being unfamiliar with VBScript but don't worry about it.  VBS shouldn't be used for client-side scripting anymore so it's really no big deal.  It exists only for backwards compatibility.  LOTS of things have changed since the early days of HTML and scripting that have been depreciated and should no longer be used/done.  But you will find that most of them still work anyway.

Comment: Here is a working example of using VBScript to address two DIVs that have the same IDs: http://www.illuminati-r-us.com/VBScriptTest.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82529/discussion-between-powergamer-and-lance).

Comment: @PowerGamer I've completely rewritten my answer.  I am tagging you here just so you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense to me, but here is the explanation;

Since the `for` attribute links to an `id` and not a `class`, it will only detect the first `id` of it's type.

This is what I would define as the expected behaviour due to the fact that any page should only ever have a single element with an `id` name - if you need multiple elements with the same identifying name, use a `class`.

In summary, the `for` will always link to the first element with the id specified.

A quick JS fiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/5fz19n64/1/

You will notice that it will always put focus on the `1st username` field.